# Select all users that have a particular role (where users and roles are many-to-many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

My `users` have and belong to many `roles`, and likewise my `roles` have and belong to many `users`.

How can I select all users who have the role "editor"? How can I select all users who have **only** the role "editor"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How can I select all users who have the role "editor"?*

```
Role.find_by_name('editor').users
```

*How can I select all users who have only the role "editor"?*
For that, you'll probably have to pass pure sql condition in the 'find' method.